# After Migration from .Net core 3.1 to .Net 6.0, Unable to connect MySql host from AWS serverless application

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, aws-api-gateway, .net-6.0, aws-serverless

After migration from .Net core 3.0 to .Net 6.0, I am facing a connectivity issue with MySql Host (error details are below) from AWS Server application .Net 6 API when I publish it on the dev environment. Also tried from swagger and postman, it is returned 504 gateway time out. However, it working fine locally.
I am using Entity framework core code first with Pomelo MySql with Nuget packages
"Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.1 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2"

````
[Error] Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction: Unknown error responding to request: MySqlException:
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at NurseScalettAPI.Controllers.UserManagementController.GetCaseDetails(Int32 caseId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task last task, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction.ProcessRequest(ILambdaContext lambdaContext, Object context, InvokeFeatures features, Boolean rethrowUnhandledError)```
````

```
I have tried to remove the port number and space from the connection string 

"DefaultConnection": "server=aws-cluster-instance-1.cva0y.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;database=sample_database;user=sample_user;password=passwrd;Persist Security Info=false;Connect Timeout=60;Convert Zero Datetime=true;Allow User Variables=True;"
```

For the upgrade into .Net 6.0, I have made basic changes using [Introducing the net 6 runtimes for aws lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/)

```
public class DataContext: DbContext
    {

        protected read-only IConfiguration Configuration;
        private readonly AppSettingOptions _options;
        public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<AppSettingOptions> options)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            string mySqlCOnnectionString = _options.DefaultConnection;             
if (mySqlCOnnectionString != null)
            {
                options.UseMySql(mySqlCOnnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mySqlCOnnectionString));
            }
        }
 public DbSet<CaseDetails> CaseDetails { get; set; }
}
```

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserManagementController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICoreLogger<UserManagementController> _logger;
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userService;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public UserManagementController(IUserRepository userService, IPersistService cache, DataContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, ICoreLogger<UserManagementController> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
            _userService = userService;
            _httpContext = httpContext;
            _config = config;   
        }
        [HttpGet("{caseId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCaseDetails(int caseId)
        {
            try
            {

                var connStr1 = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Get connectionstring from appsetting : {connStr1}"); //able to print in cloudfront logs 
                
                var str = _context.Database.GetConnectionString().Split(";");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Connection string: {str[0]} , {str[2]}");

                var result = _context.CaseDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Case_Id == caseId);
                return result != null ? Ok(result) : BadRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            

        }
    }
```

Startup. cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        services.Configure<AppSettingOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(AppSettingOptions.ConnectionStrings));
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();

        //services.AddDbContext<TenantContext>();

        services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollectionProvider>(new ServiceCollectionProvider(services));

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                 options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        #region UserManagement

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.Configure<AppConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig"));
        services.Configure<S3Configuration>(Configuration.GetSection("AwsConfiguration"));
        services.Configure<SearchConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SearchConfig"));
        services.Configure<ExternalKnowledgeSource>(Configuration.GetSection("ExternalKnowledgeSource"));
        services.Configure<SQSConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("ServiceConfiguration"));

        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<UserContextManager>();
        services.AddScoped<IPersistService, CacheService>();

        #endregion

        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserServices>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserServiceAsync, UserServicesAsync>();

        services.AddSingleton<IAppConfiguration, AppConfiguration>();

        services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICoreLogger<>), typeof(CoreLogger<>));


        #region UserManagement

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
         .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
         {
             options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
             options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
             options.ReturnUrlParameter = "";
         });

        #endregion

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Nurse Scarlett API",
                Description = "Nurse Scarlett API"
            });
        });
        services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                name: "AllowOrigin",
                builder => {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
            var swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI");
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Welcome to running ASP.NET Core on AWS Lambda");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to resolve this issue for 2 days.
I will appreciate your good efforts, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you really should edit out the instace name as it could be missused

Comment: Could not connect error usually indicates that something is either wrong with the connection parameters or something blocks the connection.